# crossdomain.xml configuration

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I have to call to a web service from javascript using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://[REMOTE-SERVER-IP]:8080/api/service",
    contentType: "application/jsonp",   
    crossDomain: true,
    success: successFunc,
    error: errorFunc
});
```

I read that to grant access to the method, a "crossdomain.xml" must be created in the server  http://[REMOTE-SERVER-IP]:8080/crossdomain.xml:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
   <allow-access-from domain="[SERVICE-CALLER-IP]"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

But after doing that, when I try to call to the method, I'm getting this error from the javascript debugger:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://[REMOTE-SERVER-IP]:8080/[URL]. Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

What am I doing bad?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Do you have access to the server that runs the web service? If not, crossdomain.xml won't be any use. You should consider looking at [JSON-P](http://json-p.org/) or [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prefer two options here and both assumes that you can access the server.

- The first option is to add `callback=?` parameter to request url, and modify the server response. Server should add the callback function to the response in the following format

  callback_function_coming_from_url([your_server_response])
- The second option is to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to your server response. Or you can specify the address like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [your_client_address]`

I prefer to option 2 since it is the convenient way to accomplish your task, and also, you can control your server response, much more secure than the option 1.

You can get additional info from [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)